# git hub how to delete repository (did my home work)

Tags: github

I saw,read all possible help how to delete repo, it's look easy if you can find Option on the right of you repository, problem that I don't see it>.. 
What is wrong , all videos show this gear pic for Option on the lower right, I hvae some icons but not one I need, what is wrong, tx all
[Including this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDeG4S-mJts)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Goto: https://github.com/settings/repositories select your respository, Select setting on right > Goto bottom Delete this respository

Comment: Tx, all Got relieve...It works perfectly but now I'm on w7, why I didn't see this settings on W10 no idea....

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://github.com/dainova/swirl_courses/settings and at the bottom there's a "Danger zone" where you can delete the repository.

In the new github design they've moved the settings button to the top.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to this page https://github.com/YOUR_USER_NAME/REPO_NAME/settings

In you case the link is https://github.com/dainova/swirl_courses/settings

In the bottom part you will get the "Delete this repository" button.